# One Map and two Lists on a RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am developing a chat app and I'm handling the SearchableActivity, in which the user inputs the text that he wants to search by. The output is [this](https://i.gyazo.com/a53cb9e0ddf14de20ee8d191ba9186ec.png). As you can see, the RecyclerView shows users and/or messages. I have one List with Messages, one List with the user data from the Messages of the previous List and a Map to store the users from the Users section.

The thing is that this structure is complex on code and not very effective. If you noticed, I have the soft keyboard opened because when the users Map and the messages List are both not empty, closing the soft keyboard will provoke [this](https://i.gyazo.com/76067a89b82ccfab2dcbbe16d729252f.gif) (I'm clueless about what inflicts this behaviour) among some other inconsistencies that will even lead to the crash of the app.

Given the details above, I want to be able to show both items flawlessly. Here is the code:
**SearchableActivity.java**

```
public class SearchableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Map<String, User> searchedUsers;
    private List<Message> searchedMessages;
    private List<User> searchedMessagesUser;
    private String searchUserID;

    private TextView notFoundTV;
    private RecyclerView searchRV;
    private SearchableAdapter searchableAdapter;
    private MaterialCardView searchTipCV;

    private boolean isUserNameValid = true;
    private boolean doesMessageFitQuery = false;
    private final DatabaseReference messagesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(KEY_COLLECTION_MESSAGE);
    private final DatabaseReference usersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(KEY_COLLECTION_USER);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);

        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setUpRV();
        notFoundTV = findViewById(R.id.notFoundTV);
        searchTipCV = findViewById(R.id.searchTipCV);
    }

    private void setUpRV() {
        searchedUsers = new HashMap<>();
        searchedMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        searchedMessagesUser = new ArrayList<>();
        searchableAdapter = new SearchableAdapter(SearchableActivity.this,
                searchedUsers,
                searchedMessages,
                searchedMessagesUser
        );
        searchRV = findViewById(R.id.searchRV);
        searchRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
        searchRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SearchableActivity.this));
        searchRV.setAdapter(searchableAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_searchable, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchIT).getActionView();
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                    search(query);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    private void search(String query) {
        searchedUsers.clear();
        searchedMessages.clear();
        searchedMessagesUser.clear();
        isUserNameValid = true;

        String finalQuery = query.trim();
        if (finalQuery.isEmpty()) {
            setViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE);
            isUserNameValid = false;
        } else if (finalQuery.length() < 4 || !finalQuery.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")) {
            isUserNameValid = false;
        }

        messagesReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null && isUserNameValid) {
                    searchUser(finalQuery);
                } else {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        doesMessageFitQuery = false;
                        Message message = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                        String[] wordsFromMessage = message.getMessage().split(" ");
                        int i;
                        for (i = 0; i < wordsFromMessage.length; i++) {
                            if (wordsFromMessage[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(finalQuery.toLowerCase())) {
                                doesMessageFitQuery = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (doesMessageFitQuery
                                && (message.getSenderID().equals(CURRENT_USER.getId())
                                || message.getReaderID().equals(CURRENT_USER.getId()))) {

                            if (message.getReaderID().equals(CURRENT_USER.getId())) {
                                searchUserID = message.getSenderID();
                            } else {
                                searchUserID = message.getReaderID();
                            }
                            searchedMessages.add(message);

                            usersReference.child(searchUserID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                    searchedMessagesUser.add(user);

                                    if (isUserNameValid) {
                                        searchUser(finalQuery);
                                    } else {
                                        refreshRV();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                }
                            });
                        } else if (isUserNameValid) {
                            searchUser(finalQuery);
                        } else {
                            setViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.GONE, View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }

    private void searchUser(String finalQuery) {
        usersReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (user.getUserName().equals(CURRENT_USER.getUserName())) continue;
                    if (user.getUserName().toLowerCase().startsWith(finalQuery.toLowerCase())) {
                        searchedUsers.put(user.getId(), user);
                    }
                    refreshRV();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }

    private void setViewsVisibility(int searchVis, int searchTipVis, int notFoundVis) {
        searchRV.setVisibility(searchVis);
        searchTipCV.setVisibility(searchTipVis);
        notFoundTV.setVisibility(notFoundVis);
    }

    private void refreshRV() {
        setViewsVisibility(View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, View.GONE);
        if (searchedUsers.size() > 0 && searchedMessages.size() > 0) {
            setupRV(searchedUsers, searchedMessages, searchedMessagesUser);
        } else if (searchedUsers.size() > 0) {
            setupRV(searchedUsers, new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
        } else if (searchedMessages.size() > 0) {
            setupRV(new HashMap<>(), searchedMessages, searchedMessagesUser);
        } else {
            setViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.GONE, View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void setupRV(@NotNull Map<String, User> searchedUsers,
                         @NotNull List<Message> searchedMessages,
                         @NotNull List<User> searchedMessagesUsers) {
        searchableAdapter = new SearchableAdapter(
                SearchableActivity.this,
                searchedUsers,
                searchedMessages,
                searchedMessagesUsers
        );
        searchRV.setAdapter(searchableAdapter);
    }
}
```

**SearchableAdapter.java**

```
public class SearchableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final Map<String, User> searchedUsers;
    private final List<User> searchedMessagesUsers;
    private final List<Message> searchedMessages;

    private int messageListPosition;
    private boolean areUsersLeft = true;

    public static final int NO_ITEM = -1;
    public static final int ITEM_USER = 0;
    public static final int ITEM_MSG_SENT = 1;
    public static final int ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED = 2;

    public SearchableAdapter(Context context, Map<String, User> searchedUsers, List<Message> searchedMessages, List<User> searchedMessagesUsers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.searchedUsers = searchedUsers;
        this.searchedMessages = searchedMessages;
        this.searchedMessagesUsers = searchedMessagesUsers;
        messageListPosition = 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case ITEM_USER:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_user_searched, parent, false);
                return new SearchableAdapter.UserHolder(view);
            case ITEM_MSG_SENT:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_recent_chat_sent, parent, false);
                return new SearchableAdapter.MessageSentHolder(view);
            case ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_recent_chat_received, parent, false);
                return new SearchableAdapter.MessageReceivedHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case ITEM_USER:
                String key = (String) searchedUsers.keySet().toArray()[position];
                ((SearchableAdapter.UserHolder) holder).bind(searchedUsers.get(key), position);
                break;
            case ITEM_MSG_SENT:
                ((SearchableAdapter.MessageSentHolder) holder).bind(
                        searchedMessages.get(messageListPosition),
                        searchedMessagesUsers.get(messageListPosition),
                        messageListPosition
                );

                if (messageListPosition + 1 != searchedMessages.size()) {
                    messageListPosition++;
                }
                break;
            case ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED:
                ((SearchableAdapter.MessageReceivedHolder) holder).bind(
                        searchedMessages.get(messageListPosition),
                        searchedMessagesUsers.get(messageListPosition),
                        messageListPosition
                );

                if (messageListPosition + 1 != searchedMessages.size()) {
                    messageListPosition++;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (!searchedMessages.isEmpty() && !searchedUsers.isEmpty()) {
            return searchedUsers.size() + searchedMessages.size();
        } else if (!searchedMessages.isEmpty()) {
            return searchedMessages.size();
        } else if (!searchedUsers.isEmpty()) {
            return searchedUsers.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (areUsersLeft && !searchedUsers.isEmpty() && position < searchedUsers.size()) {
            if (searchedUsers.size() - 1 == position) {
                areUsersLeft = false;
            }
            return ITEM_USER;
        } else if (!searchedMessages.isEmpty()) {
            if (!searchedUsers.isEmpty() && messageListPosition < searchedMessages.size()) {
                if (searchedMessages.get(messageListPosition).getSenderID().equals(Constants.CURRENT_USER.getId())) {
                    return ITEM_MSG_SENT;
                } else {
                    return ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED;
                }
            } else if (searchedUsers.isEmpty() && position < searchedMessages.size()) {
                if (searchedMessages.get(position).getSenderID().equals(Constants.CURRENT_USER.getId())) {
                    return ITEM_MSG_SENT;
                } else {
                    return ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED;
                }
            }
        }
        return NO_ITEM;
    }

    class UserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView profileIV;
        public TextView defaultProfileTV, usernameTV, aboutTV, usersSectionTV;

        public UserHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            defaultProfileTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.defaultProfileTV);
            usernameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTV);
            aboutTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.aboutTV);
            profileIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIV);
            usersSectionTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usersSectionTV);
        }

        void bind(User user, int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                usersSectionTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            usernameTV.setText(user.getUserName());
            aboutTV.setText(user.getAbout());
            showProfilePic(defaultProfileTV, profileIV, user);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> openChat(user));
        }
    }

    class MessageReceivedHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView defaultProfileTV, usernameTV, dateLastMesTV, previewMessageTV, messagesSectionTV;
        public ImageView profileIV;
        public CardView statusCV;

        public MessageReceivedHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            defaultProfileTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.defaultProfileTV);
            usernameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTV);
            dateLastMesTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateLastMesTV);
            previewMessageTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.previewMessageTV);
            profileIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIV);
            statusCV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusCV);
            messagesSectionTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messagesSectionTV);
        }

        void bind(Message message, User user, int position) {
            statusCV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (position == 0) {
                messagesSectionTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            usernameTV.setText(user.getUserName());
            previewMessageTV.setText(message.getMessage());

            formatDate(dateLastMesTV, message.getDate());
            showProfilePic(defaultProfileTV, profileIV, user);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> openChat(user));
        }
    }

    class MessageSentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView defaultProfileTV, usernameTV, dateLastMesTV, previewMessageTV, messagesSectionTV;
        public ImageView profileIV, seenIV, notSeenIV;
        public CardView statusCV;

        MessageSentHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            defaultProfileTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.defaultProfileTV);
            usernameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTV);
            dateLastMesTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateLastMesTV);
            previewMessageTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.previewMessageTV);
            profileIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIV);
            seenIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seenIV);
            notSeenIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notSeenIV);
            statusCV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusCV);
            messagesSectionTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messagesSectionTV);
        }

        void bind(Message message, User user, int position) {
            statusCV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (position == 0) {
                messagesSectionTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (message.isSeen()) {
                seenIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notSeenIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                seenIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notSeenIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            usernameTV.setText(user.getUserName());
            previewMessageTV.setText(message.getMessage());
            showProfilePic(defaultProfileTV, profileIV, user);
            formatDate(dateLastMesTV, message.getDate());
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> openChat(user));
        }
    }

    private void formatDate(TextView dateLastMesTV, String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date currentDay =  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date chatDay = new Date(Long.parseLong(date));
        if (formatter.format(currentDay).equals(formatter.format(chatDay))) {
            dateLastMesTV.setText(
                    DateFormat.getTimeInstance(
                            DateFormat.SHORT,
                            Locale.getDefault()
                    ).format(chatDay)
            );
        } else {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy", Locale.getDefault());
            dateLastMesTV.setText(dateFormat.format(Long.valueOf(date)));
        }
    }

    private void showProfilePic(TextView defaultProfileTV, ImageView profileIV, User user) {
        if (user.getImageURL().equals(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_URL_DEFAULT)) {
            defaultProfileTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            defaultProfileTV.setText(user.getUserName().substring(0, 1));
        } else {
            profileIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(user.getImageURL())
                    .circleCrop()
                    .into(profileIV);
        }
    }

    private void openChat(User user) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_USER, user);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome. Maybe the logic behind the Lists/Map can be simplified, I don't know. I cannot think clear enough anymore. Here is the relevant database structure just in case:

```
> Message
> > (message ID)
> > > date
> > > message
> > > readerID
> > > seen
> > > senderID
```

```
> User
> > (user ID)
> > > about
> > > id
> > > imageURL
> > > lastSeen
> > > userName
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few days, I have come up with a workaround. I have changed the structure for a simpler one, even though this implies more code. I put a ViewPager2 inside the SearchActivity in order to have one tab for the users and one for the messages, instead of showing them all in the same RecyclerView. This way, not only the code is simpler, but it also helps to show the results of the query definitely cleaner than the prior approach. Here is the code:

**SearchActivity.java**

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager2 searchVP2;
    private String globalQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        setupActionBar();
        setupViewPager();
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void setupViewPager() {
        searchVP2 = findViewById(R.id.searchVP2);
        searchVP2.setAdapter(new SearchPagerAdapter(this));

        TabLayout searchTL = findViewById(R.id.searchTL);
        TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(searchTL, searchVP2, (tab, position) -> {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    tab.setText(R.string.users);
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    tab.setText(R.string.messages);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        tabLayoutMediator.attach();

        searchTL.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                searchInCurrentFrag(globalQuery, tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_searchable, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchIT).getActionView();
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                globalQuery = query;
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                    searchInCurrentFrag(query, searchVP2.getCurrentItem());
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    private void searchInCurrentFrag(String query, int position) {
        if (query != null) {
            Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("f" + position);
            if (currentFragment instanceof SearchUserFragment) {
                ((SearchUserFragment) currentFragment).searchUser(query);
            } else {
                ((SearchMessageFragment) currentFragment).searchMessage(query);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**SearchPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class SearchPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public SearchPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new SearchUserFragment();
        } else {
            return new SearchMessageFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**SearchMessageAdapter.java**

```
public class SearchMessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<User> searchedMessagesUsers;
    private final List<Message> searchedMessages;

    //Result codes
    public static final int ITEM_MSG_SENT = 0;
    public static final int ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED = 1;

    public SearchMessageAdapter(Context context, List<Message> searchedMessages, List<User> searchedMessagesUsers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.searchedMessages = searchedMessages;
        this.searchedMessagesUsers = searchedMessagesUsers;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case ITEM_MSG_SENT:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_recent_chat_sent, parent, false);
                return new SearchMessageAdapter.MessageSentHolder(view);
            case ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_recent_chat_received, parent, false);
                return new SearchMessageAdapter.MessageReceivedHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case ITEM_MSG_SENT:
                ((SearchMessageAdapter.MessageSentHolder) holder).bind(
                        searchedMessages.get(position),
                        searchedMessagesUsers.get(position)
                );
                break;
            case ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED:
                ((SearchMessageAdapter.MessageReceivedHolder) holder).bind(
                        searchedMessages.get(position),
                        searchedMessagesUsers.get(position)
                );
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return searchedMessages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (searchedMessages.get(position).getSenderID().equals(Constants.CURRENT_USER.getId())) {
            return ITEM_MSG_SENT;
        } else {
            return ITEM_MSG_RECEIVED;
        }
    }

    class MessageReceivedHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView defaultProfileTV, usernameTV, dateLastMesTV, previewMessageTV;
        public ImageView profileIV;
        public CardView statusCV;

        public MessageReceivedHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            defaultProfileTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.defaultProfileTV);
            usernameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTV);
            dateLastMesTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateLastMesTV);
            previewMessageTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.previewMessageTV);
            profileIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIV);
            statusCV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusCV);
        }

        void bind(Message message, User user) {
            statusCV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            usernameTV.setText(user.getUserName());
            previewMessageTV.setText(message.getMessage());

            formatDate(dateLastMesTV, message.getDate());
            showProfilePic(defaultProfileTV, profileIV, user);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> openChat(user));
        }
    }

    class MessageSentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView defaultProfileTV, usernameTV, dateLastMesTV, previewMessageTV;
        public ImageView profileIV, seenIV, notSeenIV;
        public CardView statusCV;

        MessageSentHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            defaultProfileTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.defaultProfileTV);
            usernameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTV);
            dateLastMesTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateLastMesTV);
            previewMessageTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.previewMessageTV);
            profileIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIV);
            seenIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seenIV);
            notSeenIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notSeenIV);
            statusCV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusCV);
        }

        void bind(Message message, User user) {
            statusCV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (message.isSeen()) {
                seenIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notSeenIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                seenIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notSeenIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            usernameTV.setText(user.getUserName());
            previewMessageTV.setText(message.getMessage());
            showProfilePic(defaultProfileTV, profileIV, user);
            formatDate(dateLastMesTV, message.getDate());
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> openChat(user));
        }
    }

    private void formatDate(TextView dateLastMesTV, String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date currentDay =  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date chatDay = new Date(Long.parseLong(date));
        if (formatter.format(currentDay).equals(formatter.format(chatDay))) {
            dateLastMesTV.setText(
                    DateFormat.getTimeInstance(
                            DateFormat.SHORT,
                            Locale.getDefault()
                    ).format(chatDay)
            );
        } else {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy", Locale.getDefault());
            dateLastMesTV.setText(dateFormat.format(Long.valueOf(date)));
        }
    }

    private void showProfilePic(TextView defaultProfileTV, ImageView profileIV, User user) {
        if (user.getImageURL().equals(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_URL_DEFAULT)) {
            defaultProfileTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            defaultProfileTV.setText(user.getUserName().substring(0, 1));
        } else {
            profileIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(user.getImageURL())
                    .circleCrop()
                    .into(profileIV);
        }
    }

    private void openChat(User user) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_USER, user);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**SearchUserAdapter.java**

```
public class SearchUserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final Map<String, User> searchedUsers;

    public SearchUserAdapter(Context context, Map<String, User> searchedUsers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.searchedUsers = searchedUsers;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_user_searched, parent, false);
        return new SearchUserAdapter.UserHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String key = (String) searchedUsers.keySet().toArray()[position];
        ((SearchUserAdapter.UserHolder) holder).bind(searchedUsers.get(key));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return searchedUsers.size();
    }

    class UserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView profileIV;
        public TextView defaultProfileTV, usernameTV, aboutTV;

        public UserHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            defaultProfileTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.defaultProfileTV);
            usernameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTV);
            aboutTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.aboutTV);
            profileIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIV);
        }

        void bind(User user) {
            usernameTV.setText(user.getUserName());
            aboutTV.setText(user.getAbout());
            showProfilePic(defaultProfileTV, profileIV, user);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> openChat(user));
        }
    }

    private void showProfilePic(TextView defaultProfileTV, ImageView profileIV, User user) {
        if (user.getImageURL().equals(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_URL_DEFAULT)) {
            defaultProfileTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            defaultProfileTV.setText(user.getUserName().substring(0, 1));
        } else {
            profileIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(user.getImageURL())
                    .circleCrop()
                    .into(profileIV);
        }
    }

    private void openChat(User user) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_USER, user);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**SearchUserFragment.java**

```
public class SearchUserFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView notFoundTV;
    private RecyclerView searchUserRV;
    private MaterialCardView searchTipCV;
    private Map<String, User> userMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_message, container, false);
        notFoundTV = view.findViewById(R.id.notFoundTV);
        searchTipCV = view.findViewById(R.id.searchTipCV);
        refreshRV(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void refreshRV(View view) {
        userMap = new HashMap<>();
        searchUserRV = view.findViewById(R.id.searchMessageRV);
        searchUserRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
        searchUserRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }

    public void searchUser(String query) {
        userMap.clear();
        boolean isUserNameValid = true;

        String finalQuery = query.trim();
        if (finalQuery.isEmpty()) {
            setViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE);
            isUserNameValid = false;
        } else if (finalQuery.length() < 4 || !finalQuery.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")) {
            setViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE);
            isUserNameValid = false;
        }

        if (isUserNameValid) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child(KEY_COLLECTION_USER)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        if (user.getUserName().equals(CURRENT_USER.getUserName())) continue;
                        if (user.getUserName().toLowerCase().startsWith(finalQuery.toLowerCase())) {
                            userMap.put(user.getId(), user);
                        }
                        checkList();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setViewsVisibility(int searchVis, int searchTipVis, int notFoundVis) {
        searchUserRV.setVisibility(searchVis);
        searchTipCV.setVisibility(searchTipVis);
        notFoundTV.setVisibility(notFoundVis);
    }

    private void checkList() {
        if (userMap.size() > 0) {
            refreshRV(userMap);
            setViewsVisibility(View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, View.GONE);
        } else {
            setViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.GONE, View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void refreshRV(@NotNull Map<String, User> userMap) {
        SearchUserAdapter searchUserAdapter = new SearchUserAdapter(
                getContext(),
                userMap
        );
        searchUserRV.setAdapter(searchUserAdapter);
    }
}
```

**SearchMessageFragment.java**

```
public class SearchMessageFragment extends Fragment {

    private final DatabaseReference messagesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(KEY_COLLECTION_MESSAGE);
    private final DatabaseReference usersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(KEY_COLLECTION_USER);

    private TextView notFoundTV;
    private RecyclerView searchMessageRV;
    private MaterialCardView searchTipCV;

    private List<Message> messageList;
    private List<User> userList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            searchMessage(getArguments().getString(BUNDLE_SEARCH));
        }*/
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_message, container, false);
        notFoundTV = view.findViewById(R.id.notFoundTV);
        searchTipCV = view.findViewById(R.id.searchTipCV);
        setupRV(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void setupRV(View view) {
        messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        searchMessageRV = view.findViewById(R.id.searchMessageRV);
        searchMessageRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
        searchMessageRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }

    public void searchMessage(String query) {
        messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        userList = new ArrayList<>();

        messagesReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    boolean doesMessageFitQuery = false;
                    Message message = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    String[] wordsFromMessage = message.getMessage().split(" ");
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < wordsFromMessage.length; i++) {
                        if (wordsFromMessage[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(query.trim().toLowerCase())) {
                            doesMessageFitQuery = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (doesMessageFitQuery
                            && (message.getSenderID().equals(CURRENT_USER.getId())
                            || message.getReaderID().equals(CURRENT_USER.getId()))) {

                        String searchUserID;
                        if (message.getReaderID().equals(CURRENT_USER.getId())) {
                            searchUserID = message.getSenderID();
                        } else {
                            searchUserID = message.getReaderID();
                        }
                        messageList.add(message);

                        usersReference.child(searchUserID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                userList.add(user);
                                checkList();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
                        });
                    } else {
                        setViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.GONE, View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }

    private void setViewsVisibility(int searchVis, int searchTipVis, int notFoundVis) {
        searchMessageRV.setVisibility(searchVis);
        searchTipCV.setVisibility(searchTipVis);
        notFoundTV.setVisibility(notFoundVis);
    }

    private void checkList() {
        if (messageList.size() > 0) {
            refreshRV(messageList, userList);
            setViewsVisibility(View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, View.GONE);
        } else {
            setViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.GONE, View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void refreshRV(@NotNull List<Message> searchedMessages,
                           @NotNull List<User> searchedMessagesUsers) {
        SearchMessageAdapter searchMessageAdapter = new SearchMessageAdapter(
                getContext(),
                searchedMessages,
                searchedMessagesUsers
        );
        searchMessageRV.setAdapter(searchMessageAdapter);
    }
}
```

I'm completely aware of the duplicity of some code, but refactoring is not my main concern right now. The thing is that the search feature works great currently.